# diff if statements

Tags: actionscript-3

I`m pretty much new in as3 and I came with a doublet, the statements 'if' bellow, do the same think?

```
public function get products(a:Object){
    if(a){
     // smtg
    }
    if(null!=a){
     // smtg
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your question whether they do the same thing? or why do they do the same thing?

Comment: Do they do the same comparison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not the same. While they behave similar in many cases, there is the big difference, that the first method evaluates the value, while the second just checks if the value is not null.

You can see the difference with this example:

```
function test ( a:Object ):void
{
    if ( a )
        trace( "A" );
    if ( a != null )
        trace( "B" );
}

test( false ); // B
test( "" ); // B
test( 0 ); // B
test( true ); // A & B
// ...
```

All values that evaluate to *false* will produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a being an object `a` can be not null, but still `false`, so `if (a)` and `if(a != null)` could potentially yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

`if (a)` is different from `if (a != null)`.

The latter only checks for equality between `a` and `null`; the former converts `a` to `Boolean` and then checks if the result is `true`.

The former is essentially:

```
if (Boolean(a))
  ...
```

What happens when `a` is converted to `Boolean` depends on `a`'s type. You can find the rules here (see "Casting to Boolean"):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html

In my tests I've found that the `if (a)` is *twice as fast* as `if (a != null)`, even when `a` is an object and not a string or a number.